# Android: copy selected by finger area from photo

Tags: android, camera, copy, photo, crop

I need to crop taked by camera image, but not with rectangle. User should pass round by touch an area on the image and then this area should be copyed/erased.

How to determine an area on the photo which user traced round? And erase it then?

Comment: did you find out the solution?

Comment: if you find solution then please share it ...